# PostgreSQL in windows

Tags: r, postgresql

I am using an R code which parse the SEC forms. This code store data into a PostgreSQL database.

I am getting this error when trying to connect to PostgreSQL Database. May be I need the commands that I should run in PostGreSQL to create the user’s and DB.
I am using windows 10.

```
pg <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL())
```

> Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
>     RS-DBI driver: (could not connect user7@localhost:5432 on dbname "user7": FATAL:  role "user7" does not exist
>   )

Comment: You may also need to pass your authentication credentials/dbname etc. to the driver

Comment: Thanks Mako for your help. How can I create the athentification credentials in PostregSQL. I am using windows and Newbie with this DB. Can you give some steps

Answer (score 0):

General connection string looks like this:

```
library(DBI)
library(PostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

connection <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "postgres",
                 host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                 user = "postgres", password = "password")
```

Comment: > connection <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "postgres",
+                         host = "localhost", 
+                         user = "admin", password = "password")
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect admin@localhost:5432 on dbname "postgres": FATAL:  role "admin" does not exist
)

Comment: @AdamZ2 it might be worth using something other than R to figure out what the right settings are, one less complication to get in the way

Comment: @AdamZ2 “admin” and “password” need to be replaced by *your* credentials, same with dbname, port, and host

Comment: `\conninfo` in `psql` will tell you what your username, host, and port are.

Comment: Thanks Mako: I didn't create any account yet in PostGreSQL. Can I do it from R?

Comment: Sam : How can I do it outside R? Do you know how to create accounts and DB inside PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sounds like you should start by reading some intro guides to Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tutorial-start.html

Comment: Mako: Thanks. I am using PostregSQL in windows. I ahve found no file "conninfo"

Comment: That’s a PSQL command, not a file. If you don’t know what that is, please read some introductory postgresql documentation.